# Which version of Oracle instant client download should I use for Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracleclient, occi

I have a requirement to connect to oracle database for this I am using OCCI as programming language. I would like is there any restriction on which client version can be used for a corresponding database i.e. Database to which I am connecting is at version 10.1.0.4. Now can I used 11 Client?

Comment: Yes, that will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle client versions are generally backward compatible. Unless the server is too old. As long as it is a version greater then 10 it should be fine.

Have a look at the link below. There is a matrix showing interoperability details between client and server versions.

http://orcl.tistory.com/entry/Oracle-Client-Server-Interoperability-Support